# Black Images when rendering: image editor does not work

Tags: rendering, image

My rendered 3D model is correct, light and camera are on and it displays nicely in the rendering mode in 3D view.

However, when I hit the render button the rendered image is black. Here is a screenshot.

[image]

Do you have any idea about what could cause this problem?

Anyway thanks a lot!

Cheers

Comment: Could it be that you didn't unwrap your model or forgot to assign the textures? For other issues you should consider to upload the .blend file (e.g. http://pasteall.org/blend/ and add a link here).